# Possible to change Eclipse suggested 'quick fix' for synthetic accessor warning?

Tags: java, eclipse, warnings

The first suggested fix for accessing a private member variable from within an anonymous class is:

> Change visibility of 'foo' to 'default'

I personally have never liked the non explicit nature of the default permissions in Java. In addition I would like the most restrictive permissions that will eliminate the warnings.

The ideal would be if Java had a 'file private' level permission but it does not.

My question is whether it is possible and how one can change the Eclipse suggested fix to 'protected' instead of 'default'?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is contradictory. The `default` visibility modifier **[is more restrictive](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)** than the `protected` modifier. That's why eclipse suggests that one. You should use that suggested value.

If you ever need the protected modifier for a field due to creating a sub class of it, then eclipse will suggest exactly that. So during a longer period of development you may first change the modifier of the same field to default and then to protected, but you should not go for protected by default.

If you want to create high quality source code, your personal liking of a language feature should have much lower priority than established best practices and coding guidelines.

Comment: I appreciate your points. However, I think that there is no clear answer as to whether default or protected is more restrictive -- they prevent access from different but overlapping sets. In particular, protected is far more restrive if the class is final.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to change a quick fix although it is possible to add your own.

See this question: [How do I configure Eclipse to create protected java methods by default instead of private?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610007/how-do-i-configure-eclipse-to-create-protected-java-methods-by-default-instead-o)

There is [Poor Man's Quick Fix Eclipse plugin](http://www.jave.de/eclipse/poormansquickfix/) but it is from 2008 and I have not tried it.